# In GWTP, what are the difference of onBind, prepareFromRequest, revealInParent, onReveal, onReset in Context of Present-ChildPresenter? Very Confused

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I am using GWTP, I am also using NestedPresenter in a form of parentPresenter (Ex: HeaderPage) and childPresenter (ContentPage). I also want to send info from parentPresenter to childPresenter (Ex: when user Loginned in HeaderPresenter then the info will be pass onto the childPresenter).

Now, I am very confusing about the difference among onBind, prepareFromRequest, revealInParent, onReveal, onReset.

Google said (https://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_do_I_choose_between_onReveal()_and_onReset()?) "On First Load, onBind will be called first then prepareFromRequest will be called sencond, revealInParent called 3rd, then onReveal, then onReset".

So here are the list of my questions:

-When a page that have Header & Content, then cycle (onBind, prepareFromRequest, revealInParent, onReveal, onReset) will be called **first** in parent header presenter, then after that all same cycle (onBind, prepareFromRequest, revealInParent, onReveal, onReset) will be called **second** in child or nested content presenter?

Or both parentPresenter & childPresenter go through the cycle independently?

If they go through the cycle independently, then we can have a problem. Ex, whenever user refreshes the page (header+content), if the header already checked the session, then I want the header pass the session info into the child content page, but since they go through the cycle independently then how parent presenter pass info when child presenter has not initialized?

Second question is how to know which method should to be put put into which cycle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your web application can be seen as a tree of Presenters. Walking the tree from **bottom to top**,  `onBind` will be called on each Presenter. Once all Presenters are bound, `onReveal` will be called on each Presenter, from the **top to the bottom** of the tree. The `prepareFromRequest` method will be called before `onReveal`.

So, `onBind` will be called first on ChildPresenter, then `onBind` will be called on ParentPresenter, then `onReveal` will be called on ParentPresenter, and finally `onReveal` will be called on ChildPresenter.

There's no risk that ChildPresenter will not be initialized when ParentPresenter checks the session.

To communicate from the ParentPresenter to the ChildPresenter, I suggest 2 approaches:

- When the session is fetched by ParentPresenter, ParentPresenter fires a `SessionLoadedEvent` through the `EventBus`, and ChildPresenter registers to that event and reacts to it
- When the session is fetched by ParentPresenter, ParentPresenter calls `childPresenter.onSessionFetched(sessionData)` directly. ChildPresenter will do whatever he wants with `sessionData` inside the `onSessionFetched` method.

You can also see this https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Presenter-Lifecycle

Comment: so i put the method that pass info from parent to child in the onReset of ParentPresenter cos at that time onBind & onReveal already called in childpresenter so there no risk that they r not initialised. Is that right?

Comment: From what I understand, your ParentPresenter is your app's header. So it's only going to be revealed once (correct me if I'm wrong). Fetching the user's session would be done inside the ParentPresenter's onReaveal method.

Comment: no it's won't work properly. Let say I have page1 (header+content1), page2(header+content2). if i fetch the session into onReveal of parentPresenter in page1, then the code work ok on Page1, but when I open page2, then the header in pager got session info but the content2 did not receive info that should be passed from header in page2

Comment: You should store the session info in a User object, that is a Singleton. Just pass that User instance around, and you'll be able to share session state anywhere in your app